# Unity: Infinite While Loop in Coroutine

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine, coroutine

Okay so I'm trying to create a small dash coroutine for my 2d character. When the coroutine calls, gravity switches off, he lerps between 2 speeds over a time. The issue is within my Dash coroutine, the while loop checks when time.time(current time) > start time + dash duration.

While debugging this with Mono, I'm finding that my variable currentTime is not changing after being set, even though I can clearly see the while loop running more than once. This puts me in an infinite loop.

Any suggestions?

```
    void Update () {
    MoveAndJump ();
    CheckDash ();
    }




void MoveAndJump(){

    if(dashing){
        return;
    }

    Vector2 moveDir = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    rb.velocity = moveDir;

    // Consider Switching to an overlap circle based on the actual character graphic. This currently uses a rectangle
    // This can also use 4 points to create a more complex box shape. This only works well when using at least about 1 unit size. any smaller and it is innacurate
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapArea (groundPoint_right.position, groundPoint_left.position, groundMask);
    Debug.Log (isGrounded);

    if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") == 1) {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1 , 1 * transform.localScale.y, 1* transform.localScale.z);
    } else if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") == -1) {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1, 1* transform.localScale.y, 1* transform.localScale.z);
    }


    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded){
        rb.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpHeight));
    }
}


void CheckDash(){
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && !dashing && Time.time > nextdashtime){
        dashing = true;
        StartCoroutine ("Dash");
    }
}

IEnumerator Dash(){
    //Before dash loop
    rb.gravityScale = 0f;
    float startDashTime = Time.time;
    float endDashTime = startDashTime + dashDuration;
    float currentDashTime;
    //Dash Loop
    while(Time.time < (startDashTime + dashDuration)){
         currentDashTime = Time.time;
        // The value to lerp by should be the % that time.time is between start time and end time
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 (Mathf.Lerp (startDashSpeed, endDashSpeed, ((currentDashTime - startDashTime) / (endDashTime - startDashTime))),0f);
    }

    //When dash loop is complete
    nextdashtime = Time.time + dashcooldown;
    dashing = false;
    rb.gravityScale = 1;
    yield return null;
}



// FOR CHECKING GROUND CHECK LIMITS
/*void OnDrawGizmos(){
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawLine (groundPoint_left.position, groundPoint_right.position);
}*/
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot a yield return null within my while loop that stuck me in an infinite loop. Works fine now.

```
 while(Time.time < (startDashTime + dashDuration)){
     currentDashTime = Time.time;
    // The value to lerp by should be the % that time.time is between start time and end time
    rb.velocity = new Vector2 (Mathf.Lerp (startDashSpeed, endDashSpeed, ((currentDashTime - startDashTime) / (endDashTime - startDashTime))),0f);
    yield return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need all that for *dashing* !**

If you use rigid bodies then the following code will do:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
    public float Force = 10;

    private void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        ForceMode? forceMode = null;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) // normal
            forceMode = ForceMode.Force;
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) // dash
            forceMode = ForceMode.Impulse;

        if (forceMode.HasValue)
            _rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward*Force, forceMode.Value);
    }
}
```

This is an example using 3D but you have the same for 2D : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html

**Steps:**

- add rigidbody component to your ground, set it as kinematic
- add rigidbody component to your player
- sketch the above component for your player using `Rigidbody2D` class
- adjust the parameters as you'd like
- you should have a simple and robust *dashing* by now :)

Comment: I need more control than an impulse in this situation. I need to be able to control the speed over time.

Comment: Then use the different overloads and force modes of the rigid body. You can also try constant force : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ConstantForce.html